# Data Access Layer Fires DataBound Twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a data access layer object to handle query execution. The problem is that when I call it, it ends up running through `Item_DataBound` twice so something is not right here. Thank you in advance.

```
Case "DataGrid"
    If Len(DataValueField) > 0 Then
        Dim oDS As New DataSet
        Dim oDV As New DataView
        oDV = DataTable.DefaultView
        oDV.Sort = DataValueField & " ASC"
        oDS.Tables.Add(oDV.ToTable)
        CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = oDS
        CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
    Else
        CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
        CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
    End If
    CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
    CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
```

Comment: You seem to have posted a fragment of a `Select Case`. It's not clear how the code relates to your question. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the incomplete snippet you have two DataBinds no matter what the length of DataValueField...

```
Case "DataGrid"
If Len(DataValueField) > 0 Then
    Dim oDS As New DataSet
    Dim oDV As New DataView
    oDV = DataTable.DefaultView
    oDV.Sort = DataValueField & " ASC"
    oDS.Tables.Add(oDV.ToTable)
    CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = oDS
    CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()   'FIRST IF DATAVALUEFIELD LEN>0
Else
    CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
    CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()   'FIRST IF DATAVALUEFIELD LEN=0
End If
CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()    'SECOND DATABIND HAPPENS IN EITHER CASE
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't see that. I'm a ding dong.

Comment: @Stelmerfudd ... if my answer was useful please mark as correct... many thanks.